# WCF Service, how to get the web site URL from within a class library?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a WCF service running in IIS that calls a function in a class library where httpContext is available. How can I dynamically get the web site url, this may also be a virtual directory?

Comment: The url for the WCF service or the url for the site that is the source of the HttpContext?

Comment: URL for the site hosting the WCF service... for example:http://localhost/virtualDirectory from http://localhost/virtualDirectory/myService.svc

Comment: Which version of IIS? IIS 6 or 7 or 7.5? Is WAS implemented?

Comment: @John, out of curiosity, why remove C# from the title?

Comment: @Russell: it's already in the tags. In the title, it's redundant. The title should be the entrance point to the question. But people are already filtering on tags in the Questions lists. Many, if not most, would never see a C# question if they weren't interested in C#, so why tell them in the title, what they already know from the fact that they see the question at all?

Comment: @Russell: also, the question has nothing to do with C#. C# happens to be the language he's using to access .NET. The answer would be identical in VB.NET or F#, with the programming language being the only difference. The tag is enough to tell answerers what language to use in the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a ServiceHostFactory which launches your service host manually, then store the endpoint address in a static class to be used by your application. Here is a simple example:

(in your myService.svc):

```
<%
 @ServiceHost
 Service="MyNamespace.MyService" 
 Factory="MyNamespace.MyServiceHostFactory"
  %>
```

(in your MyServiceHostFactory.cs):

```
/// <summary>
/// Extends ServiceHostFactory to allow ServiceHostFactory to be used.
/// </summary>
public class MyServiceHostFactory : ServiceHostFactory
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new ServiceHost using the specified service and base addresses.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="serviceType"></param>
    /// <param name="baseAddresses"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
    {
        ServiceHost host;
        host = new ServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses);

        MyGlobalStaticClass.Address = baseAddresses[0]; // assuming you want the first endpoint address.

        return host;
    }
```

(In your MyGlobalStaticClass.cs):

```
  public static string Address = "";
```

Answer (score 27):

I'm going to start by assuming that you're using HTTP - I'm sure you can adjust the approach depending on what your specific conditions dictate.  I tried to get an answer using HttpContext as well and found out that the value was null when running under Cassini so I tried an alternative approach.

System.ServiceModel.OperationContext contains the proper request context.  You can follow the request down to the actual request message and scrub the header.

```
Uri requestUri = System.ServiceModel.OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage.Headers.To;
```

Answer (score 4):

Currently I am working on WCF REST Service and I have same kind of requirement. I need service Host URL in my one of method. Here below is the different ways to get WCF REST Service Host/URL in class library.

You can use `WebOperationContext` class which availables in `System.ServiceModel.Web` namespace to getting service url. Please note this class is only for WCF REST Service.

1. `WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers["host"]` - Gives Service Host Name
2. `WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.UriTemplateMatch.BaseUri.Host` - Gives Service Host Name
3. `WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.UriTemplateMatch.BaseUri.AbsoluteUri` - Gives Service Full Url
4. `WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.UriTemplateMatch.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri` - Gives Service Full Url

You can get more information about `WebOperationContext` class on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.weboperationcontext.aspx)

Comment: For me, UriTemplateMatch is always null, so I can't use 3/4 of these suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not too hot on WCF as I'm more used to .Net 2.0, but would this do it?

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString()
```

That should give you the url of the calling request. The catch here is that you could possibly have multiple domains or virtual directories pointing to the same service and it will only give you the url the client specified. However if you have multiple entry points, there is no "one" url anyway.

Comment: This also assumes the WCF binding is basicHttpBinding or HTTP binding of sorts (eg netTcpBinding does not have a HttpContext).