# Is it possible to change a WCF service's ServiceHostFactory using attributes?

Tags: c#, wcf

I just came from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822774/wcf-service-how-to-get-the-web-site-url-from-within-a-class-library) which describes how to set a custom ServiceHostFactory on the `.svc` file markup to add some custom functionality.

Now I'm curious. Can this be done via custom attributes on the `.svc.cs` end? i.e. probably something like:

```
[ServiceContract]
[Factory("MyApp.MyCustomHostFactory")]
public class MyService {
    // do backflips
}
```

I know you can use custom attributes to (inject) custom behavior into services and operations, but this looks like something that's abstracted deeper than what I've seen so far from the likes of `IServiceBehavior` and `IOperationBehavior` etc etc.

If it can be done, how should I do it? What should I use? A simple push in the right direction would be really helpful. :)

Comment: I think generally which factory to use is more regarded as a deployment issue. You can customise it in the .svc file or, if using fileless activation in WAS on IIS, in the <serviceActivations> element of the config file.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is probably something that you should not do via an attribute, as it is something that feels more like a deployment thing and so I would favour doing it in the serviceActivations part of the config file, but in the interest of answering this question...

You *could* create your own attribute - the accepted answer to [Simplifying configuration of WCF4 RESTful service routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145863/simplifying-configuration-of-wcf4-restful-service-routes) would be one way of doing it.